# Set Timer in adaptive card

Tags: adaptive-cards, adaptive-design, adaptive-layout

I am trying to build a microsoft adaptive card with timer on top of the card and once timer expires automatically a action should invoked. Is this possible in adaptive card?

Comment: Feel free to make this suggestion on our Roadmap: https://aka.ms/ACRoadmap

Answer (score 2):

As of today this is not possible.

Cards are just "UI", you can not run any scripts, timers or any automatic functionality in a card without user interaction. This might change in the future but the current version can't do this.

Sorry not to have any better news.